# How to call the c# script from objective-C code in Unity?

Tags: plugins, unity-game-engine

In Unity, Wen can call objective-C code from C# by import the function of objective-C as extern function.
But how call C# script code from objective-C ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
UnitySendMessage("GameObjectName1", "MethodName1", "Message to send");
```

in which you fill your gameobject name which will receive this message and the message name.

You can implement your own delegate/event once you receive this message from native code. The limit of UnitySendMessage is when it arrives to Unity code, it is always 1 frame after you call this in native code. And it can only take string as parameter. But most of time it is not big problem.

Answer (score 2):

The method to be used for this is UnitySendMessage. Have a look at [Building Plugins for iOS](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html) or this [blog](http://www.cnblogs.com/pengyingh/articles/2340812.html) which is partially written in Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: http://www.tinytimgames.com/2010/01/10/the-unityobjective-c-divide/
The bolg post shows a technique that uses KVO ([Key Value Observation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)) and the PlayerPrefs to pass commands from unity to objective-c.

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("Commands",
   String.Format("AwesomeCommand|{0}|{1}", awesome1, awesome2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can create a callback method that will allow you to do whatever you want.

Here is an example video showing it being done for OSX, but the C++ code is cross platform.

This guy has been doing videos on plugins for all the operating systems, but the mac one is the coolest so far, since it gives you function pointers to C# code.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2dDK0ulDYY

Answer (score 0):

Universal plugin for unity for iOS that allow mixing C# with objective-C
http://goo.gl/XDrQFh

Unity C#

```
var callbackClass = AKiOSMagic.CreateClass("MyCallbackClass", "NSObject");
callbackClass.AddMethod("methodWithArg:anotherArg:", (args)
{
    // do something...
    // args.GetObject(0);
    // args.GetObject(1);
});
callbackClass.RegisterClass();
```

Objective-C

```
[[NSClassFromString(@"MyCallbackClass") new] methodWithArg:@"arg1" anotherArg:@"arg2"]
```